# Intersection of "positive" open half-spaces

Tags: linear-algebra

Prove that the intersection of "positive" open half-spaces associated with any basis
$x_1,x_2, \ldots, x_n$ of a finite dimensional inner product space $(V,(\cdot,\cdot))$ is non-empty.

Recall that the "positive" open half-space associated with $x_i$ is the set $A_i=\{y \in V|(y,x_i)>0\}$.

I got a hint that: Let $z_i$ be the projection of $x_i$ on the orthogonal
complement of the subspace spanned by all basis vectors except $x_i$, and consider
$t =\sum r_iz_i $ when all $r_i > 0$.)

However I couldn't find the proof yet. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am assuming that $V$ is a real vector space.

Let $P$ be the intersection of the positive half spaces.

Let $\phi:\mathbb{R}^n \to V$ be given by $\phi(y) = \sum_k y_k x_k$, note that $\phi$ is a bijection.
Define an inner product on $\mathbb{R}^n$ by $\langle a,b \rangle_V = (\phi(a),\phi(b) )$, where $(\cdot, \cdot)$ is the inner product on $V$. Let 
$Q$ be the matrix defined by $[Q]_{ij} = \langle e_i ,e_j \rangle_V$.

We have $\langle a,b \rangle_V = \sum_{ij} a_i b_j [Q]_{ij} = \langle a , Qb \rangle$, where the latter inner product is the standard inner product on $\mathbb{R}^n$.

Let $A = \{ a | \langle a, e_k \rangle_V >0\}$, and note that
$\hat{a}= Q^{-T} (1,1,...,1)^T \in A$.

Since $P = \phi^{-1}(A)$, we see that $\phi^{-1}(\hat{a}) \in P$ and
hence $P$ is not empty.

Comment: Thank you @copper.hat. Since your notation had a bit different to mine so I would like to address some questions. I suppose so $V=\mathbb R^n.$ What did your notations $y_k,x_k,e_k$ mean? And I don't really get the point of "Define an inner product on $\mathbb R^2$ by $\langle a,b \rangle_V = (\phi(a),\phi(b) )$".  Why $\mathbb R^2$ here? Thank you.

Comment: I don't really understand your question. $V$ is an abstract finite dimensional real vector space, $\phi$ provides the connection between $V$ and $\mathbb{R}^n$. You have an inner product on $V$, I want to add an inner product on $\mathbb{R}^n$ that is compatible with $(\cdot,\cdot)$ on $V$. $y \in \mathbb{R}^n$, so each $y_k \in \mathbb{R}$. The $x_k$ are from your question and the $e_k$ are the standard unit vectors in $\mathbb{R}^n$ (that is, $e_1 = (1,0,0,...), e_2=(0,1,0,0,...)$, etc.).

Comment: The $\mathbb{R}^2$ was a typo. (since fixed).

Comment: As an aside, if $V=\mathbb{R}^n$, one answer could be the solution of $\begin{bmatrix} x_1^T \\ \vdots \\ x_n^T \end{bmatrix} a = \begin{bmatrix} 1 \\ \vdots \\ 1 \end{bmatrix}$. (Or any strictly positive right hand side, for that matter.)

Comment: Thank you @copper.hat. If we assume that $V=\mathbb R^n$ then your terminologies "$(\cdot, \cdot)$ is the inner product on $V$" and "the latter inner product is the standard inner product on $\mathbb{R}^n$" are identical isn't it?

Comment: Dear @copper.hat. Can you give me the explanation why the equation $[x_1^T \ldots x_n^T]^T a = [1 \ldots 1]^T$ always has solution?. This would be a very nice solution for me.

Comment: Because the $x_i$ are linearly independent, and there are $n$ of them, the matrix formed by them is invertible. (Your matrix should either be the one I had above or $[x_1^T \ldots x_n^T]$.)

Comment: Thank you @copper.hat. I got it.

Comment: Dear @copper.hat. At the last line of your proof, did you mean that $P=\phi^{-1}(A)?$

Comment: @user: I did, thanks for catching that!

Comment: Am I correct in saying that in order for this proof to work over $\mathbb{C}$ we just need to take $\hat{a}$ to be the conjugate transpose of $Q^{-1}$ times $(1,1,\dots,1)^T$? The rest goes through with no issue?

Comment: @SamWeatherhog: I am sure some modification would work, but you need to define half space when the field is complex first.

Comment: What does $Q^{-T}$ mean?

Comment: @BillyO.: The inverse of the transpose of $Q$.

Answer (score 2):

$\newcommand{\on}{\operatorname}$
$\newcommand{\la}{\langle}$
$\newcommand{\ra}{\rangle}$

Here's a proof more along the lines of the hint prescribed. Let's let $\la \cdot,\cdot \ra$ denote the inner product for $V$ so we don't overburden parentheses.

Let's assign

$$U_i:=\on{span}( \{ \vec{x}_1,\dots, \vec{x}_{i-1}, \vec{x}_{i+1},\dots,\vec{x}_n\}).$$

Then we let $\vec{z}_i= \on{proj}_{U_i^\perp}(\vec{x}_i)$.

Claim: the inner product $\la\vec{x}_i, \vec{z}_i\ra>0$.

In general, for a subspace $U\subseteq V$ and vector $\vec{x}\in V$, we have the inequality

$$\la \vec{x},\on{proj}_{U} (\vec{x}) \ra \geq 0,$$ because if we let $\{\vec{u}_1,\dots,\vec{u}_k\}$ be an orthonormal basis for $U$, then we can write
$$\la\vec{x},\on{proj}_U(\vec{x})\ra=\la\vec{x},\sum_{i=1}^k \la\vec{x},\vec{u}_i\ra \vec{u}_i\ra=\sum_{i=1}^k \la\vec{x},\vec{u}_i\ra^2\geq 0.$$
In the case above,the inequality must be strict because $\la\vec{x}_i, \on{proj}_{U_i^\perp} (\vec{x}_i) \ra =0$ would imply that $\vec{x}_i$ was in $U_i$, which would contradict the assumption that $\{ \vec{x}_1,\dots,\vec{x}_n\}$ is a basis. Thus the claim is proved.

Furthermore, $ \la \vec{x}_i, \vec{z}_j\ra=0$ when $i\neq j$, by construction. Thus, we can take $\vec{z}=\sum_{i=1}^n \vec{z}_n$ (or any other strict positive combination of $\vec{z}_i$'s) as a vector which satisfies the desired property that $\la \vec{z},\vec{x}_i \ra>0$ for all $i$.