# Proving a statement regarding the non-existence of a non-orthogonal vector to a set of linearly independent vectors

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $v_1, \dots, v_n \in \mathbb{R}^{n+1}$ be linearly independent vectors and let $w \in \mathbb{R}^{n+1}$ be a vector with $$v_i^\top w \geq 0 \quad \forall i \in \{1,\dots, n\}$$ and $v_j ^\top w > 0$ for some $j \in \{1, \dots, n\}$.

I want to show that there cannot exist such a vector $w$ (I would guess because then $v_1, \dots, v_n$ would not be linearly independent). Disclaimer: It would surprise me, but since I was not able to prove the statement so far, there might actually exist such a vector $w$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A counterexample is $n=2$, $v_1=(1,0,0)$, $v_2=(0,1,0)$, and $w=(1,1,1)$.

Comment: One may also ask a question: Does such vector $w$ exist for arbitrary linearly independent $v_1,\ldots, v_n$? It seems that it's true at least for $n=1$ and $n=2$.

Comment: Yes, that is a good question, which I was thinking about after this answer.

Comment: @Kulisty I think [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1119164/intersection-of-positive-open-half-spaces) should answer your question